# Asp.net MVC reg expression attribute

Tags: regex

Hello can any one help me to build a reg expression for

at least one capital letter, one lower-case letter, one number, and one punctuation

Comment: i need to reg expression for at least one capital letter, one lower-case letter, one number, and one punctuation i have tried this but does not seems to be working /^(?=.*[.,?!])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{12,}/

Comment: sorry i have very less knowledge in Regular expressions. i need to set regular expression attribute in asp.net mvc application like this                                                                        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 12)]
        [RegularExpression(@"/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).$/i", ErrorMessage = "error")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

Comment: Try a very trivial regex to begin with (e.g. `A`) and see if that works. Just to make sure you're not one of those people who copy/paste the leading and trailing slash from a regex text book assuming .NET would know it's way around that.

Comment: yes first i need to test with a simple expression. i will get back to you if need some help..Thanks @Ruud

Comment: Well, then you should acquire the necessary knowledge to build this on your own, assuming this is a good example to start learning with. If you don't want to do that, StackOverflow is maybe not a good place to come ask for help.

Comment: okay Thanks @Bartdude i'm new to forums didn't know the rules..any way thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you search

http://www.regexlib.com/

and find the one which fits your needs